# Best practice for assigning categories 'children' and 'parents' (directories nested in directories) in PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, filesystems

I have a bit of a problem here.  I am developing a custom ISO 9001 system, and have opted against WebDAV (though I haven't spent much time looking into it).

I currently have a directory with folders for departments inside of them.  Some departments have sub categories, and some sub categories have sub categories... so on and so forth.

I currently have a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
id | category | parent_id | filepath | owner | title
```

The category id is assigned to every directory that is a parent with or without children, but if that directory is nested inside another directory, it has no category ID and instead has a parentid.

I have been able to get it working; but this convoluted method I have come up with only works if the directory has one child.  So if you open all of the categories, it queries all categories which are not null.  If you select that category, it checks if there are any categories whose parentids match the category.  If so, it will list the categories, otherwise it will output the files in that directory.

This project has grown larger than anticipated, and I would like for there to be allowed more than one single nested category.  I understand my method is probably inefficient, does anyone know how to remedy this, or possibly have an existing framework to suggest?  I'd like for it to be dynamic, ie. You can have as many nested categories as you like.  Sorry if this question is outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/lixing/closure-tables-for-browsing-trees-in-sql

Comment: Thank you for that resource!  I'll have to spend some time understanding it, but it seems like a step in the right direction.